# Does $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\infty, 1-\frac{1}{n}\right) = (-\infty, 1)$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm currently trying to think of an example of a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is not compact in the topological space $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$, where $\tau = \{(-\infty, a): a\in \mathbb{R}\}\cup\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$.

I suspect that $(-\infty, 1)$ is not compact. In trying to show this, I'm hoping that an open cover can be given by $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\infty, 1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$, but this is only true if $(-\infty, 1) \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\infty, 1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$. If this is true, then certainly there is no finite subcover of $(-\infty, 1)$ coming from $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\infty, 1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$, and so $(-\infty, 1)$ is not compact.

So, does $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-\infty, 1-\frac{1}{n}) = (-\infty, 1)$?

Comment: Hint(maybe):  Whether $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\infty, 1-\frac 1n) = (-\infty, 1)$ or not will not have anything to do with you topology on $\mathbb R$ you are using.  Either $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\infty, 1-\frac 1n) = (-\infty, 1)$ "always" or it does not.  (This hint is assuming that you have actually run across this question before.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is true. To show this, just show that any number in $(-\infty, 1)$ is in $(-\infty,1-1/n)$ for some $n.$

Comment: Let $x\in (-\infty, 1)$ be arbitrary. Then $x < 1$. We want to show that $x < 1 - 1/n$ for some $n$. Assume to the contrary that $x \geq 1-1/n$. Then $n \leq 1/(1-x)$, which is a contradiction because $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x < 1$, so $1/(1-(-3)) = 1/4$ (for example). Clearly, $n \not \leq 1/4$. Is this right? I think I was able to show it by contradiction, but I didn't really gain any intuition this way.

Comment: @playitright You may wish to see the answer I posted in response to your comment.

Comment: @playitright for intuition, pick $x\in (-\infty,1),$ and draw it on the number line, somewhat to the left of $1.$ Define the distance between it and one as $1-x\equiv \epsilon >0.$ The number $1-1/n$ is also less than one and has distance $1/n.$ So it gets closer and closer to one as $n$ gets larger, eventually passing $x.$ In particular, for $n>1/\epsilon,$ $1-1/n$ is closer to one and greater than $x.$

Answer (score 4):

We wish to show that for any $x \in (-\infty, 1)$, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $x < 1 - 1/n$, or equivalently, $$n > 1/(1-x).$$  Recall the **Archimedean property** of the reals, which states that for any reals $a, b > 0$, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $na > b$.  So if we choose $$a = 1, \quad b = 1/(1-x),$$ (the latter choice being positive since $x < 1$ implies $1-x > 0$), we obtain the desired assertion, and the proof is complete.

Comment: Ah! I should probably just get Theorem 1.20 from Rudin tattooed on me at this point since it never stops showing up. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm.  It should be a fact you rattle off that for any $r >0$ there is a natural $n$ so that $0 < \frac 1n < r$.  You are allowed and can be expected to rattle that off as self-evident without proof.  (Although proving it the first time is actually not trivial.)