# How to find the set which is written as an intersection of infinite sets?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I need to find the following set

$S = \displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[2-\dfrac{1}{n} , 3 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right]$

Now using hints from these questions :[Union and intersection of the family of sets $[-1,1-\frac1n]$; describe and prove!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535802/union-and-intersection-of-the-family-of-sets-1-1-frac1n-describe-and-prov?noredirect=1&lq=1) ,and [Does $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\infty, 1-\frac{1}{n}\right) = (-\infty, 1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531740/does-bigcup-n-1-infty-left-infty-1-frac1n-right-infty-1?rq=1)

I have tried to solve this problem on my own and would like to know if it is right or wrong.

So, I claim : The given set $S =  (2,3)$

Suppose $y \in S$ then clearly $y  \gt 2$ and $y \lt 3$ Hence $y \in (2,3)$

So , $S \subset (2,3)$

Now I am having difficulty in proving the reverse claim ie How can I prove that

$(2,3) \subset S$ . I think to produce an $n$ which satisfies the given inequality I need to use Archimedian Property , But I am not sure how to do that.

I have two questions at this point.

(i) Is my proof upto given point ie $S \subset (2,3)$ correct ?

(ii) How can I show the reverse claim ?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider:  is $2\in S$?  $3\in S$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:Can you please elaborate your hint ?

Comment: $y$ need not be greater than $2$ or less than $3$.

Comment: If $y\in S$ then $y>2-\frac1n\;\forall n\in \mathbb N$ -- that means $y\ge2$, which is slightly different from what you said $(y>2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a countable intersection of closed sets is closed.

Let $x \in [2,3]$

Then $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ we have that $$2-\frac{1}{n} <2\leq  x \leq 3 < 3 + \frac{1}{n}$$

Thus $[2,3] \subseteq S$

Let $x \in S$ then $2-\frac{1}{n} \leq  x  \leq 3 + \frac{1}{n},\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$

The sequence $2+\frac{1}{n} \to 2$ and $\frac{1}{n}+3 \to 3$

also the  constant sequence $a_n=x \to x$

So $2\leq x\leq 3$ since limits of sequences preserve inequalities.

Comment: You've only shown one implication.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have one doubt ,In the first inequality where you say,                             $2-1/n \le 2$ why are you using a equality because for any $n \in N$ we will always have a strict inequality .

Comment: @zeroflank it does not matter since if somethig is bigger than something else then it will be also bigger equal.. i will edite though if you want.

Comment: @MariosGretsas: Thank you for writing such a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the boundary point, $2$ and $3$  because these  points are included in all of your sets, therefore $$S = \displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[2-\dfrac{1}{n} , 3 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right]=[2,3]$$